# Где ошибка в коде сервера?

Tags: java

Добрый день, подскажите, написал простое приложение клиент сервер задачей его ставил передачу файлов

**КЛИЕНТ**

```
public class Client_2 implements Runnable {


    static private ServerSocket server;//принимает соединение от Socket connection 
    static private Socket client;//создаёт соединение ServerSocket так же может соедениться с channel socket

    /*****************STREAM*****************/
    static private BufferedOutputStream output;
    static private BufferedInputStream input;
    /***************************************/

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread (new Client_2()).start();
        new Thread (new Server_2()).start();

    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192]; 
        int in;

        try {


            client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 60000);
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/tmp.txt"));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            while ((in = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
            output.write(byteArray,0,in);           

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
}
```

**СЕРВЕР**

```
public class Server_2 implements Runnable {


    static private ServerSocket server;//принимает соединение от Socket connection 
    static private Socket client;//создаёт соединение ServerSocket так же может соедениться с channel socket

    /*****************STREAM*****************/
    static private BufferedOutputStream output;
    static private BufferedInputStream input;
    /***************************************/

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192]; 
        int in;

        try {


            server= new ServerSocket(60000/*номер порта*/, 10/*колличество подключений*/);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D://"));
            input = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            while ((in = ((ObjectInput) output).read(byteArray)) != -1){
            ((ObjectOutput) input).write(byteArray,0,in);           

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
    }
```

но при передаче файла выдаёт ошибку

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ (Системе не удается найти указанный
>   путь)     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   ru.cod.Server_2.run(Server_2.java:37)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at ru.cod.Server_2.run(Server_2.java:50)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

В чём может быть ошибка ?

Comment: Он же вам по-русски говорит: Файл не найден. Неправильный путь.....а конкретно `new FileOutputStream("D://"));`  где файл в который надо писать?

Comment: Путь `"D://"` не может быть файлом, поэтому `FileOutputStream` не может открыть его для записи

Comment: Вообще код сервера не рабочий, начиная с `client` которому ничего не присвоено, попыток чтения из `output`, приведения `BufferedInputStream` к `ObjectOutput`.

Comment: @VargSieg чтобы записать в файл - файл должен существовать. Т.е. надо как минимум писать в `D:/file.txt`. А если его нет, то создать файл с нужным именем.Вы ведь передаете не сам физический файл, а только лишь содержимое, поэтому указание `D://` некорректно

Comment: @zRrr Да и правда client пуст, а что ему присвоить ?

Comment: Чтоб клиент не был пустым, видимо надо `Socket client= server.accept();` добавить после `server = new ServerSocket(port);` что даст ожидание, пока не прилетит на сервер запрос...... с картинкой работа аналогична.... вы передаете байты, вы считываете байты и формируете Uotput картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо указать имя файла, собственно как он и ругается.

```
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D://your_file_name"));
```

Вы пытаетесь записать в директорию данные. Это конечно тоже файл, но особый, не поддерживает запись данный. Укажите необходимое имя файла (или временное какое-то, или пусть клиент передаёт дополнительно имя файла)

Comment: Почитайте книгу по java. любую )

Comment: А зачем Вы кастуете к ObjectInput и ObjectOutput?

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно имя файла. Если вы хотите просто, чтобы данные из файла хранились - создайте просто временный файл(например системный File.createTempFile) либо же генерите в папке уникальное имя и туда сохраняйте. Вы в любом случае не сможете сохранить файл без имени. Какая у Вас задача в итоге то, что такие странные мысли по реализации возникают?

Comment: Если надо чтобы имя файла совпадало с оригиналом, Вам надо передавать с клиента по мимо самого файла и его имя.

Comment: Ну самый топорный способ, без привлечения новых знаний - это Вы формируйте новый файл в который в начале добавьте его имя. и завершите имя \x00 например. А на сервере из потока сначала вычлените имя, а остаток запишите в файл. Можно не создавать новый файл на клиенте, а просто пихнуть сначала в output имя файла потом \x00, а потом сам файл

Comment: т.е. вы сначала output.write(fileNameBuf, 0, n) а потому уже файл